# Windows 10 Start Menu Context Menu All But Settings Apps Not Starting

Tags: windows-10, start-menu, context-menu

I have a PC running Windows 10, latest updates, where when you right click on the Start Menu, all of the menu items less the ones going to the Settings applet do nothing. Such as:

- Event Viewer
- Device Management
- Disk Management
- Computer Management
- Windows PowerShell
- Windows PowerShell (Admin)

Apps and Features, Power Options, System, and Network Connections work fine.

The non-functioning applets, Event Viewer, work fine, such as starting from the Run dialog or my favorite typing in the taskbar search box.

I did try `sfc /scannow` and in the past other recommended system file restoration utilities. We even tried an upgrade, but the problem persists.

**UPDATE**

I ran the DISM command previously, just I forgot the name and syntax offhand. I ran the dual along with a restart of the computer again to the same issue. No change.

Here is the test:

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.18363.778]
(c) 2019 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

C:\WINDOWS\system32>dism.exe /online /cleanup-image /restorehealth

Deployment Image Servicing and Management tool
Version: 10.0.18362.1

Image Version: 10.0.18363.778

[==========================100.0%==========================] The restore operation completed successfully.
The operation completed successfully.

C:\WINDOWS\system32>sfc /scannow

Beginning system scan.  This process will take some time.

Beginning verification phase of system scan.
Verification 100% complete.

Windows Resource Protection did not find any integrity violations.

C:\WINDOWS\system32>
```

Comment: Open an Admin Command prompt and run: dism.exe  /online  /cleanup-image  /restorehealth  . When this completes, run SFC again, Restart and test.

Comment: @John I tried the DISM command previously, just I forgot the name/syntax. In any event, I ran your procedure along with a restart, and the result is no difference, same problem. See diagnostics above.

Comment: Thank you for the update. I have posted a Repair Install answer for you to follow. This will work in most cases

Answer (score 0):

For this issue, there is a solution that often works:  Windows 10 Repair Install.

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10

Windows 10 is running, so click on the Download button (not Upgrade Button, select Run.

This will launch the Repair and proceed normally.

1. This process will upgrade all applicable drivers.
2. This process will make you uninstall incompatible software
3. This process will not fix damaged User Profiles.
4. This will take a while and you can keep working.
5. You can choose when to start the update.
6. Your files will be right where you left them.
   It is easy to go back if you do not like it.

Please note item 3. The Repair Install does not fix damaged User Profiles.  If you do the repair and the Menu is still not there, make a new, test Windows User Profile (Account). Log into the new Account and see if the menu works correctly.